# Dismiss Popup Window on Touch Outside

Tags: java, android-studio, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to open up a pop-up window with 4 buttons on it that will dismiss when a button is pressed or when the user clicks outside of the pop-up window. I would just make an alert dialogue, but that will only support 3 buttons.

There have been a lot of questions about this same thing, and I can't find any consistent answer or any answer that works for me (including the deprecated Bitmap Drawable). I've put all of the suggestions I've seen into my code, but to no avail.

Here's everything I've used so far:

```
//to create new popup window
LayoutInflater chooseMealInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View chooseMealLayout = chooseMealInflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_meal_dialog, null);

PopupWindow chooseMealPopup = new PopupWindow(chooseMealLayout, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);


//to make popup dismiss on touch outside
chooseMealPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
chooseMealPopup.setFocusable(true);
chooseMealPopup.setContentView(chooseMealLayout);
chooseMealPopup.showAtLocation (chooseMealLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
chooseMealPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

I've tried to find everything I can, like keeping `setFocusable` before `showAtLocation`, but when I run the app, nothing happens when I click. Figured it might be something individual to my code, since I'm new and don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

don't know what you really want to do...

if you want show dialog when click button

```
YourBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //what you want to do like show dialog

        }
    });
```